XSLT Deleting the duplicate segments has issue
I have an issue while deleting duplicate segments, i have multiple HEADER/SUBHEADER/ORDER segments, in each ORDER segment, separetly i need to check for duplicate OGS11 segments without considering OGS11/SEG/SEQ1 value, if rest of the sub nodes are same under OGS11 then we can consider that as duplicate and can delete that duplicate segment.
i have used composite function as i have lot of subsegments under OGS11, but its not deleting the duplicates. Please review it once
Input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:HEADER xmlns:ns0="http://idenity.com">
    <ns0:SUBHEADER>
        <ORDER>
            <HN>
                <field1>1233</field1>
            </HN>
            <GS1>
                <field1>1</field1>
            </GS1>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>21</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>123</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>22</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>123</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>23</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>1234</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>1414</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <NEWSEGMENT>
                <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEGMENT>
            <NEWSEG1>
                <FIELD1>COUNT</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEG1>
        </ORDER>
        <ORDER>
            <HN>
                <field1>1234</field1>
            </HN>
            <GS1>
                <field1>1</field1>
            </GS1>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>21</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>123</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>22</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>123</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <NEWSEGMENT>
                <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEGMENT>
            <NEWSEG1>
                <FIELD1>COUNT</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEG1>
        </ORDER>
    </ns0:SUBHEADER>
</ns0:HEADER>




Desired output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:HEADER xmlns:ns0="http://idenity.com">
    <ns0:SUBHEADER>
        <ORDER>
            <HN>
                <field1>1233</field1>
            </HN>
            <GS1>
                <field1>1</field1>
            </GS1>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>21</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>123</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>23</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>1234</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>1414</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <NEWSEGMENT>
                <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEGMENT>
            <NEWSEG1>
                <FIELD1>COUNT</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEG1>
        </ORDER>
        <ORDER>
            <HN>
                <field1>1234</field1>
            </HN>
            <GS1>
                <field1>1</field1>
            </GS1>
            <OGS11>
                <SEG>
                    <SEQ1>21</SEQ1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
                        <FIELD2>EN</FIELD2>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG>
                <SEG2>
                    <FIELD1>5</FIELD1>
                    <SEQ>
                        <FIELD2>123</FIELD2>
                        <FIELD3>AS</FIELD3>
                    </SEQ>
                </SEG2>
            </OGS11>
            <NEWSEGMENT>
                <FIELD1>123</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEGMENT>
            <NEWSEG1>
                <FIELD1>COUNT</FIELD1>
            </NEWSEG1>
        </ORDER>
    </ns0:SUBHEADER>
</ns0:HEADER>



XSLT I used is below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:template match="*[ORDER/OGS11]">
<xsl:copy>  
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except OGS11"/>    
<xsl:for-each-group select="OGS11" composite="yes" group-by="*/*[name() != 'SEQ1']">    
<xsl:sequence select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
 
 
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>


   
        


It might be necessary to push the child elements of OGS11 through a mode that removes the SEG/SEQ1 element and then to use deep-equal on the result to eliminate duplicates; the following attempts that
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:delete" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$elements" mode="delete"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:mode name="delete" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="delete" match="SEG/SEQ1"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="ORDER">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, OGS11[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="child-map" select="map:merge(OGS11!map { generate-id(): mf:delete(*) })"/>
      <xsl:sequence 
        select="fold-left(
                  OGS11, 
                  (), 
                  function($r, $o) { 
                     if (some $o1 in $r 
                         satisfies 
                           deep-equal(
                             $child-map($o1!generate-id()),
                             $child-map($o!generate-id())
                           )
                         ) 
                         then $r 
                         else ($r, $o) 
                  }
                )"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="OGS11[last()]/following-sibling::*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

As for the problem raised in a comment about elements getting lost if there are no OGS11 elements, here is a different way to handle that:
  <xsl:template match="ORDER">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="elements-except-OGS11" select="* except OGS11"/>
      <xsl:variable name="child-map" select="map:merge(OGS11!map { generate-id(): mf:delete(*) })"/>
      <xsl:variable name="unique-OGS11" 
        select="fold-left(
                  OGS11, 
                  (), 
                  function($r, $o) { 
                     if (some $o1 in $r 
                         satisfies 
                           deep-equal(
                             $child-map($o1!generate-id()),
                             $child-map($o!generate-id())
                           )
                         ) 
                         then $r 
                         else ($r, $o) 
                  }
                )"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$elements-except-OGS11 | $unique-OGS11"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


Its working as expected, but if ORDER has no OGS11 segment then its completely removing the ORDER segment, how can we avoid this.

@Pavan, the ORDER itself should be copied, obviously the code <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, OGS11[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/> and <xsl:apply-templates select="OGS11[last()]/following-sibling::*"/> assumes there are OGS11 elements, if that is not the case use <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, if (OGS11) then OGS11[1]/preceding-sibling::* else *"/> and  <xsl:apply-templates select="if (OGS11) then OGS11[last()]/following-sibling::* else ()"/> instead.
